# Can I override a class method in a protocol the class will conform to?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Different views in my application will need to fetch some data from a server and then perform a segue using this data: since the following VC is always the same, I thought it might be a good idea to define a protocol that will save myself from copy/pasting the code every time.

However, it looks like **I am not allowed to override the "prepare for segue" method inside the protocol my view will conform to**. Perhaps I haven't still quite got how protocols work in Swift?

Adding the override keyword will result in a "Method does not override any method from its superclass" error from the compiler, but in any case the function won't get called.

```
protocol StoreGetter : UIViewController {
    func showStore(_ storeId: String)
    /*override*/ func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) //gives compiler error with override keyword
}

extension StoreGetter {
    func showStore(_ storeId : String) {
        //... fetches data from server and eventually:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toStoreProfile", sender: store)
        //...
    }

    /*override*/ func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { //never gets called anyways
        if let storeProfileTVC = segue.destination as? StoreProfileTVC {
            if let store = sender as? Store {
                storeProfileTVC.store = store
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this is **not having to copy/paste the "prepare for segue" method in each class that will conform to this protocol** and therefore inherit the showStore method (I am currently doing this)

Another option I can think of is:

1. defining another class inheriting from UIViewController
2. conforming it to StoreGetter overriding the "prepare for segue" there
3. and using this as superclass for my other views

...**not sure** if this is a clean approach either.

What could it be the best way to work around this?

Comment: Your use case is more aligned with having a class inherit from `UIViewController` and having other classes subclass from this custom class (as mentioned in your post) instead of using a `protocol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Malik said, **protocols** don't seem to be the correct approach here.

You should create a `BaseViewController`, define your `prepareForSegue` method there and all your `UIViewController` classes should inherit from it.

Now you can override `prepareForSegue` for the `ViewController`s where you want a custom logic.